# Find all indices of maximum in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I need to find all indices where the maximum value (per row) is obtained in a Pandas DataFrame. For instance, if I have a dataFrame like this:

```
   cat1  cat2  cat3
0     0     2     2
1     3     0     1
2     1     1     0
```

then the method I am looking for would yield a result like:

```
[['cat2', 'cat3'],
 ['cat1'],
 ['cat1', 'cat2']]
```

This is a list of lists, but some other data structure is also okay.

I cannot use `df.idxmax(axis=1)`, because it only yields the first maximum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the information, in a different data structure:

```
In [8]: df = pd.DataFrame({'cat1':[0,3,1], 'cat2':[2,0,1], 'cat3':[2,1,0]})

In [9]: df
Out[9]: 
   cat1  cat2  cat3
0     0     2     2
1     3     0     1
2     1     1     0

[3 rows x 3 columns]

In [10]: rowmax = df.max(axis=1)
```

The max values are indicated by True values:

```
In [82]: df.values == rowmax[:,None]
Out[82]: 
array([[False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

[`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) returns the indices where the DataFrame above is True.

```
In [84]: np.where(df.values == rowmax[:,None])
Out[84]: (array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2]), array([1, 2, 0, 0, 1]))
```

The first array indicates index values for `axis=0`, the second array for `axis=1`. There are 5 values in each array since there are five locations that are True.

---

You could use `itertools.groupby` to build the list of lists you posted, though perhaps you don't need this given the data structures above:

```
In [46]: import itertools as IT

In [47]: import operator

In [48]: idx = np.where(df.values == rowmax[:,None])

In [49]: groups = IT.groupby(zip(*idx), key=operator.itemgetter(0))

In [50]: [[df.columns[j] for i, j in grp] for k, grp in groups]
Out[50]: [['cat1', 'cat1'], ['cat2'], ['cat3', 'cat3']]
```

Comment: ``df==DataFrame(np.tile(rowmax,len(df)).reshape(df.shape).T,index=df.index,columns=df.columns)`` will get your boolean frame (kind of like a broadcasted comparison operator); faster, but prob not more clear than the ``apply``

Comment: @Jeff: Good idea. `df.values == rowmax[:,None]` is about 10x faster still.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unless I'm mistaken, your last line should read `[[df.columns[j] for i, j in grp] for k, grp in groups]` no?

Comment: @unutbu actually I think their is an open issue to make broadcast able comparisons ( eg like div,mul and such) - can u link this too it (.or create and issue if their isn't one) thanks

Comment: gr8 thanks! interested in doing a PR?? (its not that involved!)

Comment: @Jeff: I would need some guidance; I don't have a clue what would need to be done.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
In [2560]: cols = df.columns.values

In [2561]: vals = df.values

In [2562]: [cols[v].tolist() for v in vals == vals.max(1)[:, None]]
Out[2562]: [['cat2', 'cat3'], 
            ['cat1'], 
            ['cat1', 'cat2']]
```

**Update**

Here is a full example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(400)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': np.random.randint(0,3,size=10), 
    'b': np.random.randint(0,3,size=10), 
    'c': np.random.randint(0,5,size=10),
})

print(df)

out = [df.columns[i].tolist() for i in df.values == df.max(axis=1)[:,None]]

for i in out:
    print(i)
```

Returning from `print(df)`:

```
   a  b  c
0  0  1  4
1  2  2  4
2  1  1  1
3  0  1  3
4  2  2  1
5  1  1  1
6  0  2  4
7  2  0  2
8  2  1  3
9  2  2  4
```

And from `print(out)`:

```
['c']
['c']
['a', 'b', 'c']
['c']
['a', 'b']
['a', 'b', 'c']
['c']
['a', 'c']
['c']
['c']
```

Comment: Another question (dupe) led me here. A shorter version: `[df.columns[i].tolist() for i in df.values == df.max(axis=1)[:,None]]`