# How can I get the multiple column names based on a value in pandas python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've a dataframe that contains normalized values. From each row I can obtain the maxvalue, but now I want to get also the corresponding column names.

For example df:

```
|----------------------------------------|
|    a    |     b     |   c   | 'newcol' |
|----------------------------------------|
|  0.960  |    1.00   | 1.00  |  b, c    |
|----------------------------------------|
|  0.922  |    0.955  | 0.971 |  c       |
|----------------------------------------|
```

So i want to create this newcol containing the column names that have the max values.
I've tried `df.idxmax(axis=1)` however this returns only the first column with the max value

[Find all indices of maximum in Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21627926/find-all-indices-of-maximum-in-pandas-dataframe) Tries to solve the same problem however the data is stored in a list instead of a new column in same df

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all indices of maximum in Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21627926/find-all-indices-of-maximum-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) for compare all columns with maximum:

```
df['newcol'] = df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0).dot(df.columns + ',').str.strip(',')
print (df)
       a      b      c newcol
0  0.960  1.000  1.000    b,c
1  0.922  0.955  0.971      c
```

Comment: That is working indeed, thanks for the fast response